# Variable not evaluating within jQuery CSS statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to figure this out for a good hour and I know it'll be super basic for someone out there. I'm trying to set a background with jQuery based on a variable called $the_path.

Right now the background is getting set to "$the_path" instead of the actual value of $the_path. How can I can the statement to evaluate properly?

```
$('body').css({'background' : 'url($the_path)','backgroundPosition' : 'center 50px'});
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: $the_path mean ? is it the js veriable ?

Comment: $the_path = 'images/image1.jpg';

Comment: It will always equal a relative path to an image.

Comment: $the_path is php function i guess ?

Comment: if yes then you have to use this code of piece. `$('body').css({'background' : "url('+ <?php echo $the_path; ?> +')",'backgroundPosition' : 'center 50px'});`

Comment: nope... it's a javascript variable

Comment: javascript veriable should define as `var the_path` not as `$the_path` ...

Comment: `http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp` read this ....

Comment: Wow... I feel stupid. I've been working in PHP all night and just kept defining variables the same way. No wonder I was having problems. Thanks!

Comment: you welcome. but i think i missed the points :-(

Comment: Well... I pulled equally from you and mikel. Wish I could have gone 50/50... and if it weren't for my dumb error, mikel's response would have worked. Next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep it in quotes, it'll be treated literally. To force it to be evaluated as a variable, break out of the quotes and join it using `+` instead.

```
$('body').css({'background' : "url('" + the_path + "')",'backgroundPosition' : 'center 50px'});
```

Edit: That's presuming `$the_path` is a Javascript variable. If it's a PHP variable, then you want this instead:

```
$('body').css({'background' : "url('<?=$the_path?>')",'backgroundPosition' : 'center 50px'});
```

Comment: Hmmm that still doesn't seem to be doing it. It's a javascript variable. Are we maybe confusing jQuery too much with all the stuff inside .css()?

Comment: Is $the_path from PHP ? It's a bit confusing what you mean as JS string variables don't typically begin with $. Have you tried both of my examples, exactly as written ? Also, try changing 'background' in the CSS to 'background-image' instead.

Comment: I use $ in variables for cached jQuery objects but I wouldn't use it for any other variables.

Comment: Your first example ended up working after I got rid of the $. I've been writing PHP all night and forgot to stop using the $. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`'background' : 'url('+$the_path+')'` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = 'url(' + <? $the_path ?> + ')';
$('body').css({'background' : path, 'backgroundPosition' : 'center 50px'});
```